# Changing value of span (Javascript) with Tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I have a question regarding the modification of a value inside a class. I would like to change the value with Tampermonkey extension however I cant get it to work.

The initial code looks like this:

```
<div class="bzeTileValue bzeTileValueNegative">
     <span class="bzeTileUnit">YYY</span> 
      <span>XXXX</span></div>
```

I would like to change the value of `XXXX`. Preferably before the site loads.

I tried already the `document.getElementbyId("xxxxx").innerHTML=....;` But couldn't get it to work unfortunately. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks a lot friends

Answer (score 2):

The `span` containing XXXX is inside a `div` which has classes on it but no ID.  This means that `getElementById` won't work. You can use [Document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to get the `div` and then access the [child nodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) of that `div`. The `span` you are trying to access doesn't have any classes on it, but you can target it as the second child inside the `div`. Then you can change the value using [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) or [innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText).

Altogether it looks like this:

```
document.querySelector('.bzeTileValue').children[1].innerHTML = 'New Value';
```

Comment: thanks a lot. do you know if i need to specify when the scripts needs to load. i suspect that in order for it to work is needs to be executed after the page loads right?

Comment: Also I would like to turn bzwTileValueNegative to bzwTileValuePositive. Very thankful if you could also provide quick solution to that. Thank you :)

Comment: You could use classList add and remove (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) on the document.querySelector('.bzeTileValue') element to change the classes.